# Submodule generated by a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, definition

I don't understand this definition. Can someone explain it to me and give some simple examples?

Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ a left $R$-module and $A \subset M$ some set.
The least (in terms of inclusion) submodule of module $M$ containing $A$ (i.e the intersection of all submodules of module $M$ containing $A$) we call the submodule generated by $A$ and mark $\left<A\right>$.
Every set $A$ with the property that $\left<A\right>=M$ we call a set of generators of module $M$. If

$$
A=\{a_1, \dots ,a_n\},
$$

then we denote

$$
\left<a_1, \dots ,a_n\right>=\left<A\right>.
$$

We say that a module is finitely generated (cyclic) if there exists a finite (with one element) set of generators.

Are there any equivalent definitions?

Comment: You have a few misconceptions here. A module is said to be cyclic if is has a generating set consisting of a single element. Think of cyclic groups as examples of cyclic $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. A module is said to be finitely generated if there exists a finite generating set of any size. So cyclic is a much stronger condition than finitely generated. An example of a non-finitely generated module is the Abelian group $\mathbb{Q}$ as this does not have a generating set of any finite size (can you prove this?)

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $M$ an abelian group, then $M$ is a $\mathbb{Z}-$module. So $M$ is finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}-$module (or abelian group) iff there is a $A\subset M$ with $|A|<\infty$ s.t $$M=\langle A\rangle=\langle x_1,...,x_n\rangle$$
which means that every $m\in M$ is $$m=r_1x_1+...+r_nx_n, \quad r_i\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Equivalent definition:

$M$ is finitely generated $R-$module if and only if there is a surjective $R$-linear map:
$$f:R^n\to M$$
for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: So even more simplifying, lets consider $M=Z_n$. We can write  $\left<A\right>=\left<1,...,n-1\right>$ or even $\left<A\right>=\left<1\right>$ and both statements are correct?

Comment: Yes! For more accuracy you may use $[1],...,[n-1]$ instead of $1,...,n-1$